# Colab restarts after I close the browser

Tags: google-colaboratory

I use Colab pro, open a session in a browser and type commands in the terminal. I especially install new software. But when I close the browser, my colab setting are restarted and I have to reinstall all those software again. Is there any way I can keep the software that are installed through terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, Colab automatically destroys VMs after detecting user inactivity.

[Colab Pro+](https://colab.research.google.com/signup/pricing) has a feature called **background execution**, which is exactly what you asked for: VMs persist after you close your browser. Note that Colab Pro+ costs 5x more than Colab Pro (as of 2022-01-09).

Alternatively, if the process of setting up the environment does not take a long time, I would put all the installation commands in the first cell, using [shell access](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access) (`!apt install my-things`) or [bash magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics) (`%%bash`). Thus, installing the software is done with one cell execution.